# Apex/VF How to use methods in selectOptions

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there a way to set the value of the selectionOptions to be a method with a parameter instead of a  variable?

The selection items I have are different for each line item and the picklists needs to be reassigned with different variable for each of the line item instances.

```
Pseudocode
Visualforce Page
 <apex:SelectOption value="SomeMethod(with parameter to send to controller)">
 //<actionSupport>? 

Apex:
 SomeMethod(parameter type of string from a field of an object)
{  
   test = new List<SelectOption>;


   //Add options to the list based on a field of an object. 
   //Example: list may contain string items A, B, C etc.

   return test;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Wrapper class for this.  Have a method in your wrapper that returns the SelectOptions and also have a variable directly on the wrapper that you set.  The method can then use that variable to populate values.

```
public class MyController
{
  ...

  public class Wrapper
  {
    public String myVar{get; set;}

    public Wrapper()
    {
      ...
    }

    public List<SelectOption>()
    {
      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
      if (myVar == something)
        options.add('val1');
      else if (myVar == somethingElse)
        options.add('val2');
      return options;
    }
  }
}
```